# Passing integer between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application with a couple of fragments. I would like a variable that I can edit from each fragment. I mean my main activity shows the first fragment at start. This first fragment has the following code:

```
button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left).replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_2());
            fragmentTransaction.commit ();


        }});
```

So this button opens the second fragment, but before that I would like to add 1 to that integer on button click. Then the second fragment has a similar button that should do the same. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: make a global variable in calling activity or you can use preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fragment fragment= new Fragment_2();
Bundle bdl=new Bundle();
bdl.putInt("a",1);
fragment.setArguments(bdl);

 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left).replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit ();
```

In your second fragment,

```
int a=getArguments().getInt("a");
```